# ¿Como puedo enviar un archivo de una carpeta con una peticion POST en python 3x?

Tags: python, python-3.x

estoy aprendiendo a trabajar con rest y en una api de un sistema de facturación, me piden que ponga en un header un bearer + token y envíe un archivo csv en una determinada web. El problema es que a la hora de mandar el archivo me arroja error 500 y no manda nada. El archivo se genera en un programa en visual 6.0 y hago toda la estructura del csv ahí y el token es aleatorio y lo obtengo con otra petición. Mi único problema radica en este punto y Este es mi código

```
URL2="https://ose-gw1.efact.pe:443/api-efact-ose/v1/document"
cadenaEnvio="Bearer " +  token
hd={"Authorization":cadenaEnvio,"Content-Type":"multipart/form-data"}

PATH ="C:\FACTURAS"
for filename in os.listdir(PATH):
    content = open(os.path.join(PATH, filename)).read()

fin = filename
files = {'file': fin}
r = requests.post(URL2, headers=hd,)
print(r)

if r.status_code != 200:
   print('error: ' + str(r.status_code))

else:
print('Archivos Enviados')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No veo que tu código envíe en el POST nada, pues sólo le pasas unas cabeceras, pero no un "contenido". Tampoco entiendo por qué iteras por los ficheros de una carpeta, cuando has dicho que sólo hay que enviar un fichero. ¿Quizás es que  esa carpeta sólo contiene un fichero?

La forma de subir un fichero vía POST es un tanto farragosa, pues tienes codificarlo en MIME, etc. Por suerte la biblioteca `requests` se ocupa de esos detalles si le pasas un parámetro `files` que sea un diccionario con:

- Clave = nombre que espera el servidor en ese campo del formulario
- Valor = referencia al fichero abierto en modo binario (objeto de tipo `file`)

En ese caso no necesitas pasar la cabecera `Content-type` que será automáticamente generada por `requests`.

Por tanto supongo que lo siguiente debería funcionar (asumo que la carpeta sólo contiene un fichero, por lo que, en lugar de iterar por ella, tomo el primer -y único- elemento).

```
URL2 = "https://ose-gw1.efact.pe:443/api-efact-ose/v1/document"
cadenaEnvio = "Bearer " +  token
hd = {"Authorization": cadenaEnvio}

PATH =r"C:\FACTURAS"
filename = os.listdir(PATH)[0]
files = { filename: open(os.path.join(PATH, filename), "rb") }

r = requests.post(URL2, files=files, headers=hd,)

if not r.ok:
   print('error:  {} {}'.format(r.status_code, r.reason))
else:
   print('Archivos Enviados')
```